# MS ACCESS: Print a report based on a recordset instead of record_ID

Tags: printing, report, recordset

Desperate and weekend in sight, I cannot stop until I fix this. Please bear with me...

- I am on a subform that fetches some data from excel files. (Functions like a search form)
- With the submit button, I put the search results into the table with a recordset. (code below)

  ALL THIS WORKS FINE! Now, I want to print a report from the same record I just added with the code below.
  How can I do this? As I'm currently on a form that has no record_ID (because it's for searching only)

  How do I print out the report, with the current "item_ID" (the one I just added)???

  `Private Sub Submit_Click()
  Dim db As Database
  Dim rec As Recordset
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from inboundreturns_items")
  rec.AddNew
  rec("returnID") = Forms!inboundreturns.returnID.Value
  rec("ireq") = Me.ireq
  rec("item") = Me.Item
  rec("tasknumber") = Me.tasknumber
  rec("country") = Me.Country
  rec("engineername") = Me.engineer
  rec("connote") = Me.connote
  rec("status") = Me.Status
  rec.Update
  Set rec = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
  End Sub`

(FYI: The report is based on the table inboundreturns_items)

Comment: A returnID can have multiple associated items? You want to print only the one new item record? Assuming the ItemID is always incrementing up, the new record would have the maximum [ItemID]. Use a DMax() domain aggregate function to grab that value. However, this also assumes there are not multiple users accessing the db and creating new ItemID records at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Just did an experiment and this seems to work. After the rec.Update, try:

`rec.MoveLast
DoCmd.OpenReport "reportname", , , "ItemID=" & rec!ItemID`